# Moving the contents of a float to a long in Java

Tags: java, casting

The example given for this problem on the site is:

"To move the contents of a variable declared as data type float into a variable declared as data type long requires the use of _____."

Answer: a type cast

Explanation: The explicit type cast "float" is required

```
long wayHome = 123456789;

float myBoat = (float) wayHome;
```

But this appears to be doing the opposite to me -- moving a long into a float, not the other way around.

Am I wrong, or is the question wrong? Would it be implicit or typecast?

Answer (score 3):

The example given is indeed the opposite of what's described in the question's text, like you assumed.
However, assigning a `float` value to a `long` variable will also require an explicit cast, e.g.:

```
float myBoat = 123.456

long wayHome = (long) myBoat;
```

Comment: The site says that implicit conversion is allowed from byte->short->int->long->float->double, based on how many bits of storage each type has. But I thought long is 64-bit, and float is 32-bit, so how is this allowed?

Comment: Implicit conversion from any integer type (byte/short/int/long) to any floating point type (float/double) is allowed. It's not about bits of storage, it's just how Java designers decided things to be. It's not always safe. For example if you're trying to convert int to float (both use 4 bytes for storage), `16777216` and `16777217` will become the same float value.